# How to use lsof to find high activity file writing?

Tags: files, filesystems, lsof, bandwidth, pcmanfm

I recently discovered that a buggy program called pcmanfm was writing 200 MB per second to its run.log file, so I had to find ways to combat that. I discovered what file it was that it was writing to in a laborious manner: du -h for various directories trying to find the offending file.

I'm now faced with another similar situation. Something is filling up my hard drive and I have no idea what it is, although I can guess.

Is there a way to use lsof to find out what 1 or 2 files are being written to at a high rate?

- Can I sort the file list by file size?
- Can I sort the file list by writing rate i.e. bytes/second?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`iotop`](https://www.tecmint.com/iotop-monitor-linux-disk-io-activity-per-process/)?

Comment: See also `fatrace`.

Comment: check `htop`  as well

Comment: I'll try `sysdig` on the pile as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am finding that **iotop** is quite effective, however it updates its display too rapidly to allow for cut-and-paste of anything like PIDs and program paths.

UPDATE: This requires use of the -d option to specify an update delay.

UPDATE 2: On Raspbian, sysdig is not available and fatrace is broken.

Comment: iotop does have a delay option (-d). This post also may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714485/calculate-total-disk-i-o-by-a-single-process